# How can I know which type of process of linux will use for these?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, scheduled-tasks

if I am listening to an audio file, creating  a presentation, and downloading something from the internet...while we know that:
an audio file will use real-time
creating a presentation will use interactive
and downloading will use background

but what I cannot know is for example: when an audio file will use real-time, will it use FIFO or RR ??

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the output of the [`ps(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) with the `-O cls`, e.g.:

```
~$ ps -O cls -A
  PID CLS S TTY          TIME COMMAND
    1  TS S ?        00:00:31 init [2]  
    2  TS S ?        00:00:01 [kthreadd]
    3  TS S ?        00:00:06 [ksoftirqd/0]
    5  TS S ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u:0]
    6  FF S ?        00:00:01 [migration/0]
    7  FF S ?        00:00:17 [watchdog/0]
    ...
```

The `CLS` column gives you the scheduling priority of the thread.